# A correct understanding of the proposal

Tags: meaning-in-context, terminology

I have this sentence:

> "Whether the toString function can be applied successfully to a host
>   object is implementation-dependent"

What is the meaning of "**implementation-dependent**"?

P.S If you need additional information, inform me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a common phrase in the computer world, but unknown in ordinary English.

It means that the language or system specification does not say whether or not you can do this: somebody implementing the system can choose to let you, or choose not to.

Comment: Oops, I just accepted the editing, which slightly distorted the meaning. I wanted to ask what does "implementation-dependent" refer to? To a host object or to the toString function?

Comment: @MaximPro - the phrase "implementation-dependent" refers to the **successful application** of the toString function.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realise what your problem was. The subject of the sentence is the clause _Whether the toString function can be applied successfully to a host object_.

Comment: @CanadianYankee I think you are right!